# I'm looking for WW1 weapon recordings

Tags: weapon, field-recording

Hi,

I'm looking for WW1 weapon recordings.
I've tried all major soundlibraries ( SI, HE, etc.) but i can't seem to find these :

MAUSER MG08

MAUSER G98

CHAUCHAT (Machine Rifle Model 1915 CSRG)

Hotchkiss M1909 machine gun

Vickers machine gun

Browning BAR

I'm willing to pay a decent price for good recordings.

Any help is welcome.

JAN.

Answer (score 4):

Jan, I have a huge, unique, collection of vintage weapons...many from WWI. Would be happy to help, if I can.  Please let me know how I can get in touch with you.  annk@soundmountain.com

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jan,

It's very unlikely you'll find recordings of these weapons. They're probably exist now only as museum showpieces.

The BOOM Library team released some sound packs dedicated to modern and historical weapon (for example, http://www.boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/historical-firearms). You could ask them or Ric Viers (Blastwave FX) about possibilities of recording the guns you need.

You also can try to imitate them with sound design, constructing from other elements. It'll take much more time though.

Answer (score 0):

i have a friend who have a lot WW1 weapon, he collect them, and most of them are working.
Contact me if u r interested, we could record for u.

bohitomi@gmail.com